# Non-monotonic functions on ordered sets

Tags: functions, order-theory

I'm trying to prove that if $~~(A,<_A)~~$ and $~~(B,<_B)~~$ are linearly ordered sets and $~~f: A \rightarrow B~~$ is non-monotonic function than there exist points $~~a,b,c\in A~~$ such that $~~ a <_A b <_A c~~$ and ($f(b)<_B\min\{f(a),f(c)\}~~$ or $~~\max\{f(a),f(c)\}<_Bf(b)$)

But unfortunately nothing better than brute-force enumeration of possibilities comes to my mind. So i'll be grateful for any tips or solutions for this question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

We can try *by contradicition*.

The negation of the statement to be proved is :

> for all points $a,b,c \in A \quad [ \lnot (a < b < c) \lor \lnot (f(b) < \min \{ f(a),f(c) \} \lor    \max \{ f(a),f(c) \} < f(b)) ]$

which is :

> for all points $a,b,c \in A \quad [ (a < b < c) \rightarrow (f(b) \ge \min \{ f(a),f(c) \} \land \max \{ f(a),f(c) \} \ge f(b)) ]$

which is :

> for all points $a,b,c \in A \quad [ (a < b < c) \rightarrow (\min \{ f(a),f(c) \} \le f(b) \le \max \{ f(a),f(c) \} ) ]$

and this - it seems to me - contradicts non-monotonicity of $f$.

Comment: While proving your last paragraph i'm again stuck with the same problem. I can't find the way to prove it except listing all possible variants :(

Comment: Suppose we're given your last passage. Let's take arbitrary $x,y\in A, x <_A y$. Then by linearity of order $f(x) \leq_B f(y)$ or $f(y) \leq_B f(x)$. Suppose the first one is the case. Then we need to prove that for all $a,b\in A$ if $a<_A b$ then $f(a) \leq_B f(b)$. But how? (

Comment: @user161431 - As I've written : I'm not sure ... but, what is non-monotonicity ? we have to define it. It seeme to me that in order to establish non-m we need three point $a < b < c$ such that the function $f$ "change slope" when going from $a$ to $c$. Thus, it is : $\exists a,b,c (f(a) < f(b) \land f(b) > f(c))$ or the other possibility. In every case -it seems to me - it contradicts the last passage ...